# Cocos-2dx JS can't load scene from JSON file with version 3.10.0.0

Tags: json, cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos-2dx JS for a game project. The Cocos version I use is 3.10. To create the GUIs of my game, I used Cocos Studio and then I generate JSON file of said scene using Cocos Studio. However, the generated JSON file version is 3.10.0.0, and when I compile my project, it got the error "JSON is undefined". When I changed the version attribute of the JSON file to 2.1.0.0, the project run without a problem. Anyone has experienced same error can explain why this happens and how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution that works well for me. All you need to do is go to the Cocos Studio project folder and open ***YourProjectName.cfg***. Find two lines that look something like below.

```xml
<CreateFrameworkVersion Value="cocos2d-x-3.10.0.0" />
<CurrentFrameworkVersion Value="cocos2d-x-3.10.0.0" />
```

Modify the value of CreateFrameworkVersion and CurrentFrameworkVersion to ***"cocos2d-x-2.10"***. Then, save it. Now, whenever you publish the project, the JSON file version will be 2.10.

Remember you have to close your Cocos Studio project first.